# Правильное построение навигации через конфиг

Tags: reactjs

Как передать параметр config.routes[n].title в компонент?

**config.js**

```
let config = {
    routes: [
        {
            id: 'home',
            path: '/home',
            title: 'Главная',
            component: Root
        }, {
            id: 'about',
            path: '/about',
            title: 'О Компании',
            component: About,
        }, {
            id: 'contact',
            path: '/contact',
            title: 'Контакты',
            component: Contact
        }
    ],
};
export default config;
```

**Navigation.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {NavLink} from "react-router-dom";
import config from '../config';

export default class Navigation extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            routes: config.routes,
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="navigation">
                <ul className={"navigation-container"}>
                    {
                        this.state.routes.map((route) => (
                            <li><NavLink to={route.path} id={route.id}>{route.title}</NavLink></li>
                        ))
                    }
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

**App.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import config from './config';
import Error from './pages/Error';
import Navigation from './components/Navigation';

class App extends Component {
    _isMounted = false;

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            name: 'React',
            city: undefined,
            cart: [],
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this._isMounted = true;
        if ( this._isMounted ) {
            this.setState({
                routes: config.routes,
            });
        }
    }

    render() {
        if (!this._isMounted) {
            return <div className={"loading"}>Loading...</div>
        } else {
            return (
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <Navigation/>
                    <Switch>
                        {
                            this.state.routes.map(route => (
                                <Route path={route.path} component={route.component} />
                            ))
                        }
                        <Route component={Error}/>
                    </Switch>
                </BrowserRouter>
            );
        }
    }
}

render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Используй `cloneElement`... https://reactdev.ru/reference/cloneElement/  Будет нечто такое `cloneElement(config.routes[n].component, {title: config.routes[n].title})`

Comment: @ksa, я правильно понял, что это надо добавить в Switch? Что-то типа такого:

`<Switch> 
    { this.state.routes.map((route, index) => (
        <Route key={index} path={route.path} render={e =>
            cloneElement(route.component, {title: route.title})
        />
    ))}
    <Route component={Error}/>
</Switch>`

Comment: Я не знаю в каком месте ты это собрался делать... Я лишь рассказал как такое можно организовать.